# Carousel with links outside

Tags: bootstrap-4

i have a carousel and beside list items. I want to this list items was links that caoursel will switch beetwen links.

Which atribute use to switch in direct carusel item.

https://inoroz86.000webhostapp.com/

I want to switch carusel item when i click "example" i want to switch carusel to carusel-item1...

Comment: You can change the value of href through jquery attr() function easily...

Comment: In link i preper better example my problem

Comment: I think you asked for a link over there, here it is: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp

Answer (score 0):

I will add data-slide-to="" like in idicators, then addClass and removeClass to active link via jquery and problem solved